# PHP, mysql Password reset not initiating

Tags: php, mysql, html

new here so please go easy on me. I have this simple php page which when you use, you enter your username and password. the problem is i cant seem to reset it. Basic background is, the database is called My_Details and the table is called My_DetailsData. This is the form itself:

```
<form action="reset.php" method="post">
<p align="center">Type in below, your Username, Password and New Password to reset your       login id.</p>
<table id="form_pword_reset">
<tr><td>Username</td><td>: <input type="text" name="USERNAME" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td>: <input type="password" name="PASSWORD_HASH" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>New Password</td><td>: <input type="password" name="PASSWORD_RESET" /></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td> <input type="submit" value="Reset Password" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

It links to a php page called reset.php
on the page, everything works fine, except that when i change the password on the html page, the database table is not affected at all...

```
$db_select=mysql_select_db("My_Details",$conn) or die(mysql_error());

//Retrieving data from html form
$username = $_POST['USERNAME'];

$password = $_POST['PASSWORD_HASH'];

$password_reset = $_POST['PASSWORD_RESET'];

//for mysql injection (security reasons)

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$password_reset = mysql_real_escape_string($password_reset);

$login = mysql_query("select*from My_DetailsData where USERNAME='$username' and  PASSWORD_HASH='$password'");

if(mysql_num_rows($login)== 1){
mysql_query($conn, "UPDATE My_DetailsData SET PASSWORD_HASH=$password_reset WHERE       USERNAME='$username' AND PASSWORD_HASH='$password'");

echo "Password Changed Successfully";


}
else{
echo "Incorrect Username or Password!";
}
mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: are you hashing the password ? ? i can't see you hashing the password in above code.

Answer (score 0):

please add space:

from:

```
$login = mysql_query("select*from My_DetailsData where USERNAME='$username' and  PASSWORD_HASH='$password'");
```

to:

```
$login = mysql_query("select * from My_DetailsData where USERNAME='$username' and  PASSWORD_HASH='$password'");
```

Answer (score 0):

if(mysql_num_rows($login)== 1){
mysql_query($conn, "UPDATE My_DetailsData SET PASSWORD_HASH='$password_reset' WHERE       USERNAME='$username' AND PASSWORD_HASH='$password'");

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset Password" />
<?php
if(isset($_POST['reset']))
{
$username = $_POST['USERNAME'];

$password = $_POST['PASSWORD_HASH'];

$password_reset = $_POST['PASSWORD_RESET'];
}
?>
Your Update code to

"UPDATE My_DetailsData SET PASSWORD_HASH='".$password_reset."' WHERE USERNAME='".$username."' AND PASSWORD_HASH='".$password."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$password_reset = md5($$password_reset);
    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE My_DetailsData SET password_hash ='$password_reset ' WHERE username = '$username' ");
```

Comment: hey, the problem isnt really hashing, but changing the password, i tired out your code, it worked. so could you point me in the direction of changint eh password without hashing it?

Comment: just move the  md5 from password_reset. , anyway if your login script check for hashing password then keep that way , if not then remove MD5 from password_reset

Comment: I tried this but it seems to have erased the password completely after i submit. any clues on how i can rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed the quotes for SET column='{value}'

```
 <?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$db_select=mysql_select_db("My_Details",$conn) or die(mysql_error());

//Retrieving data from html form
$username = $_POST['USERNAME'];

$password = $_POST['PASSWORD_HASH'];

$password_reset = $_POST['PASSWORD_RESET'];

//for mysql injection (security reasons)

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$password_reset = mysql_real_escape_string($password_reset);

$login = mysql_query("select * from My_DetailsData where USERNAME='$username' and  PASSWORD_HASH='$password'");

if(mysql_num_rows($login)== 1){
mysql_query($conn, "UPDATE My_DetailsData SET PASSWORD_HASH=$password_reset WHERE       USERNAME='$username' AND PASSWORD_HASH='$password'");
echo "UPDATE My_DetailsData SET 'PASSWORD_HASH`='$password_reset' WHERE       USERNAME='$username' AND PASSWORD_HASH='$password'";
echo "Password Changed Successfully";


}
else{
echo "Incorrect Username or Password!";
}
mysql_close($conn);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE My_DetailsData SET PASSWORD_HASH='$password_reset' WHERE USERNAME='$username' AND PASSWORD_HASH='$password'
                                        ^missing quotes ^
```

Comment: it doesn't really matter if the quotes are not there :).

Comment: I tried, It still doesn't seem to work.Am I missing something. just a little more information, the table My_DetailsData does not have the 'PASSWORD_RESET' row. does that make any difference?

Comment: @CharandeepPanesar I don't see `PASSWORD_RESET` in your query and I don't think it would make a difference. Are your passwords hashed because you have `PASSWORD_HASH` it might be failing because you aren't hashing new/old password and the query's failing?